# Como poner una condición para cuando una secuencia no contenga elementos de una base de datos de SQL SERVER en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Saludos tengo el siguiente error en mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es porque en la tabla que estoy llamando es porque no contiene ids/elementos que encontrar, en base a ello me gustaría implementar un condicional que ponga un cero en dicho elemento cuando suceda encuentre este caso. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private void txtTC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id_material = cmbMateriales.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (cmbUnit.Text == "English units")
        {
            //ME
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id_TM, temp, E FROM TE_I_S2 WHERE id_material = @id_material", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_material", id_material);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<double> temps = new List<double>();
            List<double> E = new List<double>();




            while (registro.Read())
            {
                
                temps.Add(Convert.ToDouble(registro["temp"]));
                E.Add(Convert.ToDouble(registro["E"]));

            }


            double[] arrayTemps2 = temps.ToArray();
            double[] arrayE = E.ToArray();
            double[] arrayTempsInv2 = Enumerable.Reverse(arrayTemps2).ToArray();




            con.Close();
     }
```

En verdad que desconozco de esto, eh investigado sin embargo no eh podido dar con una
solución.

Comment: Utiliza registro.HasRows, si es falso es porque no recupero ningún registro de la tabla

Comment: Y donde tira el error precisamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes validar el value del registro[] con una condicional en caso que sea diferente se agrega para evitar valores nulos ya que tu error es al intentar convertir un valor nulo

```
while (registro.Read())
{
   if(registro["temp"] != null) temps.Add(Convert.ToDouble(registro["temp"]));
   
   if(registro["E"] != null) E.Add(Convert.ToDouble(registro["E"]));

}
```

Si necesitas que se agregue un valor 0 cuando viene nulo usa lo siguiente

```
while (registro.Read())
{
   temps.Add(registro["temp"] != null ? Convert.ToDouble(registro["temp"]) : 0);
   
   E.Add(registro["E"] != null ? Convert.ToDouble(registro["E"]) : 0);

}
```